# How can i create two join in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 Tables:

```
**Clients**
id | names 
1  | Paul
2  | Jack

**Course** 
id | names 
1  | Med 
2  | Nur 

**Class** 
class_id | clients_id  | course_id 
1        |   1         | 1
2        |   2         | 1
3        |   1         | 2 

**I want to show this:** 

**Result**
class_id |clients_names | courses_names
1        | Paul         | Med
2        | Jack         | Med 
3        | Paul         | Nur
```

How can i get this **Result**? I already know how to make one *join*, but this *double join* is driving me crazy.

Thks.

Comment: Have you tried any thing from your side???

Comment: post what you have, the code with single join.

Comment: I have this working now:
$this->db->select('class.class_id, clients.names, course.id'); 
$this->db->from('clients');
$this->db->join('class', 'class.clients_id = clients.id');
$this->db->get();

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
select 
    c.class_id, cl.names clients_names, co.names courses_names
from Class c
join Clients cl on cl.id = c.clients_id
join Course co on co.id = c.course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CI Active Records as

```
$this->db->select('cla.class_id,cli.names as clients_names, co.names as courses_names',false);
$this->db->from('Class cla');
$this->db->join("Clients cli","cla.clients_id = cli.id");
$this->db->join("Course co","cla.course_id = co.id");
```